# SQL query takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wondering if someone can help me with this. I've got two tables. Table A contains millions of rows and I look up the entire table, Table B contains around 50 thousand rows and, again, I look up the entire table. I'm using the below query:

```
SELECT t1.ID as [ID], count(*) as [Total]
FROM table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.data LIKE '%' + t2.field3 + '%'
AND t1.ID = t2.ID

WHERE t1.ID not LIKE ''
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.datetime
```

The reason I'm using right join is because, as I understand it, it will take all the records from t2 (which I want) and only those that match them from t1. Also, I've added 'AND t1.ID = t2.ID' to the SELECT statement as I assumed this would speed up the query (not looking up IDs that don't match those in t2), although this may be negated by the RIGHT JOIN, unless my logic is entirely wrong.

Also, if I can just explain the logic behind the JOIN - the data column in table1 contains a lot of 'stuff', and somewhere in it should be exactly what is in t2.field3, e.g. t1.data = '^ABCD^00dasdas^£ldasl32^XL0005^' and t2.field3 will contain 'XL0005'.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause should be `WHERE t1.ID <> ''`

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? MySQL Oracle DB2..

Comment: If speed is an issue, what indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I'll try the WHERE clause change and the execution plan suggestion.

Comment: You should parse/extract your data (`dbo.table1.data`) into a relational format using one or more tables and then you should join all those tables without this predicate `t1.data LIKE '%' + t2.field3 + '%'` which is `horrible`. More, `LIKE '%SomeChars%'` isn't `SARG`able. So, an index on dbo.table1.data will not help you much.

Answer (score 0):

This might perform somewhat better assuming that the ID columns are indexed:

```
SELECT 
  t1.ID as [ID], count(*) as [Total]
FROM 
  table2 t2
  INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.ID=t1.ID AND t1.ID <> ''
WHERE CHARINDEX(t2.field3, t1.data) > 0
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.datetime
```

Please keep also in mind that operations such as LIKE '%'+Column+'%' or CHARINDEX do not use any indexes in the involved columns. Thus you should not expect huge improvement if you have to stick with the specific approach.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move some logic in subquery

```
SELECT t1.ID as [ID], count(*) as [Total]
FROM (select t1.ID as [ID]
            ,t1.datetime as [DATETIME]
            ,t1.data as [DATA]
            ,t2.field3 as [FEILD3] table1 t1
             RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
      HAVING FIELD2 is not null AND DATA LIKE '%' + FIELD3 + '%') as t1

WHERE t1.ID not LIKE ''
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using Like, like is real performance killer.

I have change the query please see if it solve the purpose

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(*)
       (SELECT t.*,
               CHARINDEX(t1.data,t2.field3) PRESENT
          FROM table1 t1
         RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 
            ON t1.ID = t2.ID)TEMP
 WHERE ID <> '' 
   AND PRESENT > 0
 GROUP BY ID, datetime
```

Also try placing index on `data` & `field3` columns
Try this.